# Are there any service providers for mail boxes that support POP OAuth2 downloading from another server?

Tags: email

I am looking for a mailbox service provider, preferably in Europe, that can download (as a client) through POP OAuth2 mail from another server (Exchange). GMX comes close, but it doesn't do POP with OAuth2, but rather with BasicAuth.